# how can i create a widget that loads asynchronously using ajax, js and php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Now this widget has items that should be provided by a php file.

For example the javascript should write a table in this div.

```
<div id="widget"></>
```

It should dynamically replace the content with the html provided through ajax. Does anyone know how to do this.

Also, can it be possible to create an anchor, like `<a href="onclick:reload();"></a>` to reload the article without loading the whole page. Thanks.

I would like to learn ajax, but for now this is a one off thing for now and I don't want to learn whole ajax just to create this widget, although I would like to learn it. So please provide me with sites that have tutorials on this with code or possible me help me a little with the code(that will be really very helpful :D )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the ajax call and use the onreadystatechange callback to use the response:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "/yourpage.php?get=widget", true);
xhr.send(null);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status==200) {
        var widget = document.getElementById ("widget");
                widget.innerHTML = response.xhr.responseText;
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: This requires just plain text. BTW, linus' answer considers the compatibility issues with IE<0 (use of `new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");` instead of `new XMLHttpRequest();` . Using jQuery also solves that.

Comment: Also, I'm not an expert in this, but I believe using it like that is more like a starting point to learn ajax. It is a huge security hole insert html text like that. I would rather use a json object as a response, parse it and build the widget using the json data obtained.

Comment: also what format of data would the json be in. Sorry for being such a noob.

Comment: I don't get the question. JSON would be the data format. See: http://www.json.org/ for implementations in each language (scroll to the bottom of the page).

Comment: yes...I used to include another js file in the widget file using script tags which containted the data...which was much easier to implement and would be more widely available. THanks for your great help.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a standard ajax template for something like this.  You can anchor the function to your link as you stated in the question, I named the function reload for ease.  Now, you have to have a backend script that will get the request and process it and respond.  I usually have a programname_process.php script and I send it action post variables depending on what it is trying to do.  For example, to reload a certain section, have the post variables be something like "action=reload&extent=minimum" or whatever you might need.  Then check for the action variable in your process class construct, depending on the value, send it to a function to process, and then when you get the HTML in a big string that should replace the div contents, just echo it and it will end up in the responseText variable, and poof, then appear in your div.

I went all caps in the places you need to edit for your uses:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlhttp;
function reload() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","YOUR PROCESSING SCRIPT",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("POST VARIABLES");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById('widget').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Oh, if you go with the type of class I recommended for the backend script, remember to instantiate the object outside of the class at the end in the same file as otherwise you will be working on a non-object and get errors.  Example: <?php class Process {} $process=new Process(); ?>

Comment: No jquery required mon frere.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this (using jQuery):

```
function callWidget(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "script.php",
    success: function(data){
      $("#widget").html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

And in your anchor you can use:

```
<a href="#" onClick="callWidget();">Reload</a>
```

Comment: @user658911: Of course you can. See Aleadam or linus72982 answers.